# Finding all divs with a link which has a specific id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to select the all the divs which has a sub link element with a specific id.

Structure

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="123">link</a>
</div>
```

How do I select the div with jquery?

Comment: IDs are not supposed to begin with a number.

Comment: nice that you mentioned it. But i need the id to be a number so that it auto increments in mysql.  So is there a way to have an autoincrementing id without it being a number in mysql?

Comment: You can name your ids like `id="link_1", id="link_2 ` and so on.

Comment: Perhaps also worth mentioning that IDs should be unique to the page (as "all the divs", above, makes it sound like there might be several a page). You can just as easily use a class instead.

Comment: nope, all the ids will be unique no worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:has`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$('div:has(>#123)')
```

as mentioned, you should not use numbers for ids. You can prefix them with something like `id_` and remove that when you want the actual number.

---

**update**

added the `>` to the selector used by the `:has` to only select the div that has the link as a direct child.

Comment: Note that, as it stands, this code also selects all parent divs of the div you want, as :has searches all descendents.

Comment: @D_N, good catch. updated answer to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#link-123").closest("div")
```

will get you the parent. I'd suggest giving the `div` a class so that, in case you have to insert an intervening `div` later, the code works reliably. So it'd be something like:

```
$("#link-123").closest(".link-container")
```